# How do I know if something is on the stack vs heap?

Tags: rust

In Rust there are lots of different types; how do I know if something is on the stack vs heap?

Say if I had nested structs 20 levels deep, and every level contains stack data, but at level 20 there is one heap Box, does this mean the entire tree is now on the heap?

And what about if at the root that struct is inside a Box on the heap - is all the stack based data now moved to the heap?

Are there tools to observe this stack vs heap logic?

Comment: I still don't understand people... you known that the point of an language is to hide this technical detail ? also, people should stop think stack and heap are that different. stack only difference is that it's limited and more slow, yes more slow on any modern OS

Comment: "I still don't understand people... you known that the point of an language is to hide this technical detail ?" That's true of garbage-collected languages (though even then it can be highly relevant to know this information, and many have some sort of "value type" which is generally stack-allocated), but not really true of rust. The first line of `Box` documentation is "A pointer type for heap allocation.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Rust there are lots of different types; how do I know if something is on the stack vs heap?

If nobody puts it on the heap, it's not on the heap.

> Say if I had nested structs 20 levels deep, and every level contains stack data, but at level 20 there is one heap Box, does this mean the entire tree is now on the heap?

No. `Box` is specifically a heap pointer. So whatever's inside the box is on the heap. The rest is wherever you put it (the tree could itself be in a box, at which point you'd have a heap-allocated structure pointing to an other heap-allocated structure).

Other common heap pointers are `Rc`, `Arc`, `String`, or `Vec`. And of course there are other more complicated structures which do their work on the heap without really being pointers e.g. `HashMap` and friends.

> And what about if at the root that struct is inside a Box on the heap - is all the stack based data now moved to the heap?

Yes. Since the rest of the structure is "inside" the "root", you box the entire thing.

> Are there tools to observe this stack vs heap logic?

Not really. There are tools like tracing allocators, or debugging support in some allocators (e.g. heap profiling in jemalloc), which let you, well, trace heap allocations. But all these can tell you is that some amount of bytes has been allocated, not what those bytes are exactly, and you'd only know that a heap allocation hasn't happen by deduction that no heap allocation happened.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a cost to building some state/data in the stack and then Box<T>‘ing a large tree of structs? Is the data sent from the stack to the heap?

Comment: Because Rust doesn't have a proper "placement new" in stable (yet anyway), yes. The compiler *may* be smart enough to build the thing directly in the box but there are no hard guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can profile heap usage with `valgrind` and `massif` and view the results with `ms_print`.

First profile the program:

```
$ valgrind --tool=massif ./target/debug/my_program 
==32006== Massif, a heap profiler
==32006== Copyright (C) 2003-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==32006== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32006== Command: ./target/debug/my_program
==32006==
```

The report gets written to a file named `massif.out.<pid>` (where `pid` is the process id) which you can view with `ms_print`. In the example above the process id is 32006, so view it with:

```
$ ms_print massif.out.32006
```

You'll get a lot of information, but it will point you to where heap allocations occur, with the stack traces that lead to them.